# Differences from a point in time to "now"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a Ruby on Rails app which has two main classes, one called `Instructable` and one called `Instance`.

`Instructables` hold general data about something that is a class to be taught, such as who the instructor is, a description for a still-printed book, topic and subtopic, which track it's in, etc.  It `has_many :instances`.

`Instances` are the scheduling details, and has information about where and when a particular class is being taught.

So far, simple.  Here's the tricky part.

At some point, a `PDF` is created which is sent off to be printed to be handed out to over 10,000 attendees.  This marks a potential point-in-time where we want to start publishing daily listings of class cancellations, additions, and changes.  This is where the tricky part comes in.

The `solution` I used last year was brute force.  I also saved away a copy in `CSV` format, and each time I wanted to generate a diff I would generate another `CSV` file, and use a tool to diff these.  This worked, but seems less than elegant, and as the number of instances increased, became slower.

I have tried `paper_trail` which MOSTLY works, but makes it hard to find deleted instances.  I have also written my own, which saves the original, the committed, and the changes between that are deemed "interesting" to a `Changelog` class.

Any suggestions on where to look, or clever tricks to make this all easier would be welcome.

Comment: Sounds like a time to look up [slowly changing dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension).

Comment: That is basically the strategy I defined as "save the original, and the new record in a change log" -- at least it seems to to me.  Is there something else in that article that I should know about? (I didn't know the term, but I've used the start/end time method nearly 15 years ago now, in a DNS database.  Odd how suddenly these things have names.)

Comment: Alternatively, one can use "action logs" (I don't have a good link for this :-/), but the idea is that the system doesn't have "state", only "re-playable actions" that are added to the log. The system could *also* store de-normalize stated: that is, represented by the latest action sequence. Logic maintenance is moved into the log generator, but then queries can be like: "if the last action is deleted (from a particular point in time), the course is no longer available".